# How to display response from an api call to a component whilst using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I am trying to implement an authentication system into my project and have been following this tutorial https://youtu.be/LKlO8vLvUao  .
The system works however I am trying to display the error message on a failed login attempt and I cannot figure out how to get the error message from the reducer to the component where I'd like to display it (preferably using a [msg,setMsg] hook)

Here is my code from the action where I capture the error response and pass it to reducer:

```
export const signin = (formData, history) => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    const { data }  = await API.signIn(formData);
    dispatch({ type: AUTH, data });

    history.push('/')
}
catch (error){
    const data = error.response.data;
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_FAIL", data })

 }
}
```

Here is my reducer:

```
import { AUTH, LOGOUT } from '../constants/actionTypes'

const authReducer = (state = { authData: null }, action) => {
   switch (action.type){
      case AUTH:
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify({ ...action?.data }))
        return { ...state, authData: action?.data};
      case LOGOUT:
        localStorage.clear();
        return { ...state, authData: null };
    case "AUTH_FAIL":
        return { ...state, authData: action?.data};

    default:
        return state;
}
}

export default authReducer;
```

Comment: Can you share the response `await API.signIn(formData);`  in both (Success login and Error login)?

Comment: On a succesful login the response is a profile which contains token etc that is saved to local storage in reducer. On an unsuccessful login the error is a message such as {message: "invalid credentials"}

Comment: So you should change my answer objects (`data.response.error`) in action to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Reducer create `initiateState` object

```
const initiateState: {
authData: null,
error: null
}
```

as you did in action

```
catch (error){
    **const data = data.response.error;**
    dispatch({ type: "AUTH_FAIL", data })

 }
```

also change reducer , and send the amount of `action.data` to error

```
const authReducer = (state = initiateState, action) => {
   ....//your code
       case "AUTH_FAIL":
        return { ...state, error: action.data};

    default:
        return state;
   }
}
```

using Hooks
this equal to `mapStateToProps`

```
  const error= useSelector((state) => state.error)
```

Comment: this seems to be the best way. Where would be best to insert the useSelector so that it can set a hook when an attempt to login is made? https://codeshare.io/RbnR6Q

Comment: @Tom you can get a response (error or authData )from reducer with useSelector. You can add in auth.js file

Answer (score 0):

Where you are defining the state for this reducer, break it into two parts.one being authData as it is now, the second being error. When dispatching `AUTH_FAIL`, what you should return in the reducer, is the error instead of the authData. Now in your component you can call the state anyway you like and use the updated state. I know of 2 ways for doing this:
1-mapStatetoProps
2-`store.subscribe()` and `store.getState()`

Comment: Thank you, where would I put this code in the component? I have many functions inside my component doc. https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-frost-pq88v?file=/src/Auth.js

Comment: Are you asking about mapStateToProps implementation?

Comment: I'm open to either. I've tried it a few ways but can't seem to get it right. The link before doesn't work but this is my component https://codeshare.io/RbnR6Q

Comment: I lookd at your code and I'm afraid the basics of redux isn't even set up yet. I advise you to watch a tutorial on react-redux. search for ```Traversy media react redux``` on youtube and you will find a short, amaizing tutorial on redux. But in this project, even the dependencies are not complete I'm afraid.